# want to insert record in database using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is my first time asking a question here.

So I have this PHP script

```
if($_POST['vote']){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $vote = $_POST['vote'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO question_votes ('question_id', 'user_id', 'vote', 'date') VALUES( '$id', '$log', '$vote', now())";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
}
```

Using this code

```
<script>
        $function((){
            $('.vote').click(function(){
                    var id = $(this).attr("id"); // cache $this
                    var vote = $(this).data("action");

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'ajaxvote.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {id:id, vote:vote}

                    });
                });
        });
</script>
```

When I run the code it won't insert the data in the database. By the way i'm just a student and this is my first time in website development.

Comment: Did you click on `.vote`? If it doesn't insert it, then your first task to do is checking SQL last error.

Comment: `$function((){` should be `$(function() {` : You are passing a function to `$()` as a ready handler, don't let the syntax confuse you.

Comment: can you post your html part

Comment: Where is the $log variable defined?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 0):

Few improvements and fixes.

In `if` check for `isset($_POST['vote'])` or `!empty($_POST['vote'])` to avoid run time errors.

For JS:

```
        $(function() {
        $(document).on('click','.vote',function(){
                var id = $(this).attr("id"); // cache $this
                var vote = $(this).data("action");

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajaxvote.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {"id":id, "vote":vote}

                });
            });
        });
```

Hope this helps.